# Cassandra delete query

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.1

I'm running the cassandra version with  3.0.9

this is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  datetime bigint,
   mobile bigint,
   protocol varchar,
   bytes bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (mobile, protocol, datetime)
);
```

the datetime,mobile and protocol are primary keys and therefor I created all 3 as primary key (I wanted to update the bytes for particular mobile with datetime with protocol ) but also I wanted to delete the records by only with datetime like delete all records less than particular date

T tried like this

```
delete from emp where datetime > 1000;
```

But this is not working

Anyone please help me

Comment: Show us your table schema

Comment: Put your concrete table schema, otherwise no one knows what your key looks like.

Comment: I edited the question and add the table structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like queries, you need to fully-specify your primary key components for a DELETE in Cassandra.  You can delete by partial primary key components, as long as you specify them in the correct order.  But you cannot specify only (as in your example) the last clustering key.

Example:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM emp;

 mobile | protocol | datetime | bytes
--------+----------+----------+-------
      1 |   native |      400 |     4
      1 |   native |      600 |     3
      1 |   native |     1500 |     1
      1 |   native |     1600 |     2

(4 rows)
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> delete from emp where datetime > 1000;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some 
    partition key parts are missing: mobile"

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> delete from emp 
    where mobile=1 AND protocol='native' AND datetime > 1000;

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM emp;

 mobile | protocol | datetime | bytes
--------+----------+----------+-------
      1 |   native |      400 |     4
      1 |   native |      600 |     3

(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to delete all mobile and protocol which is datetime > 1000. is there any best way ..?

Comment: @Muhunthan It depends on how many rows you are planning to delete and how big your data set is.  One thing you could try is querying for rows by `mobile` and/or `protocol` (with a script or app), and then run a delete.  Technically, that's a read before a write, but you can't delete by secondary index, and I don't *think* it'll let you delete with ALLOW FILTERING.